# How to find a specific matrix by generating random matrix

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, code-coverage

I am trying to increase coverage of my test by making a test case which will be checking the if condition of s matrix in the following program. I dont know what matrix I pass to the function `np.linalg.svd` to get the specific s matrix for my test case.
To find that matrix I created the following program and I was expecting it to run until I get that matrix. However for some reason it stops after few execution generating an error Maximum recursion depth exceeded. I dont know why it is behaving like this.
I am running it by `python program.py`
Please help

```
import numpy as np
import random
import pivot as p


def randomGenerator():
    condition = True
    while(condition):
        matrices = np.random.rand(4, 4)
        print(matrices)
        u, s, v = np.linalg.svd(matrices, full_matrices=False)
        Rank = 0
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i] < 0.01:
                s[i] = 0
                print(s)
                condition = False
            else:
                randomGenerator()
# Main #
randomGenerator()
```

Comment: If you're getting an error, please include that error in your post

Comment: It says Recursion error: maximum recursion depth exceeded.

Comment: The issue with the recursion error is that you recurse too quickly. For a singular value decomposition, the S matrix is ordered from largest to smallest. Because your `if` is inside the `for` loop, if the most important factor in S (`s[0]`) isn't `<0.01`, it triggers the else...which checks the first value in a new matrix...which triggers the else...which checks the first...(you get the idea)

Comment: This is a problem likely better solved with iteration, rather than recursion. Your while loop already generates random matrices until the condition is met, so I can;t see a good reason why it would need to be called recursively to begin with

Comment: Yes it usually goes to else part and I am trying to find a matrix which will go to if part. Yes your answer make sense. I am trying by iteration but you could alter the above code and post as answer.

Comment: Found the matrix without recursion.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is doing it without recursion. Thanks to G. Anderson.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import pivot as p

condition = True
while(condition):
    matrices = np.random.rand(4, 4)
    print(matrices)
    u, s, v = np.linalg.svd(matrices, full_matrices=False)
    Rank = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] < 0.01:
            s[i] = 0
            print(s)
            condition = False
```